# Looking for a JavaScript framework to draw dashboards based on XML or JSON description

Tags: xml, json

I'm looking for a JavaScript framework, either free or commercial, to draw dashboards based on provided XML or JSON description.

Some of the framework requirements:
 - a dashboard should be able to contain multiple text, table and chart components
 - a dashboard can be dynamically drawn in a browser window pane

I've seen [Splunk](https://apps.splunk.com/app/1603/), but want to find some more options.
IPython Notebook .ipynb format in JSON and SalesForce VisualForce XML are also good examples of what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. E.g. you should list your requirements explicitly; just [mentioning another product as reference is not sufficient](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185). Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

As Izzy mentioned, it is kind of tough to tell what you're looking for, but I think I might have a solution for you.

[ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) is a native JavaScript charting library that can be used to build quite robust dashboards. It was explicitly built for big data sets and takes JSON by default. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/external-json/) for loading in external JSON.

I'm on the ZingChart team, if you have any questions. :)